# Error on creating a node on a tree with the Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle11g, tree, oracle-adf

I have designed a tree with the Oracle ADF on Oracle HR schema.
The tree layouts are : region, country, location, department and employee. 
When I tried to create a node, the following error occurred.

```
Cannot create an object of type:java.math.BigDecimal from type:java.lang.String with value:BR
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 0):

Show some code. Basically you are trying to create a `BigDecimal` object from a String `BR`.